# PHP Variables Defined As Other Variables

Tags: php, variables, defined

I'm attempting to use PHP to make a configuration file. I have the variables set up to output to a final variable. However, when I'm trying to echo the output, it won't appear.

I've tried various solutions such as reformatting variables within the output variable.

```
<?php
   $var1 = "1";
   $var2 = "0";
   $var3 = "9";
   $varout = "{$var1}, {$var2}, {$var3};
   echo "Settings are {$varout}";
?>
```

Output:

```
Settings are {$varout}
```

Comment: it us working here :  https://eval.in/1097799

Comment: Closing double quote is missing for variable `$varout`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing double quote on your definition of $varout, add that and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concenat operator "."